# How to give permission for chown on keycloak docker images

Tags: docker, jboss, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to run my script in docker container but its throwing an error.
My docker file looks like

```
FROM jboss/keycloak

COPY db.json /opt/jboss
COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/jboss

USER root
RUN chown jboss entrypoint.sh && chmod +x entrypoint.sh
USER 1000

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD [""]
```

The error that I am getting is 
chown: cannot access 'entrypoint.sh': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c chown jboss entrypoint.sh && chmod +x entrypoint.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: have you tried specifying the full path to `entrypoint.sh` e.g. `/opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh`

Comment: That does not work

Comment: this is likely to be a permission issue

Answer (score 2):

Working Dockerfile:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak

COPY db.json /opt/jboss
COPY entrypoint.sh /opt/jboss

USER root
RUN chown jboss /opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh && chmod +x /opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh
USER 1000

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/jboss/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD [""]
```

if your directory structure looks like that

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 810 Nov 16 20:06 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121   0 Nov 16 20:07 db.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121   0 Nov 16 20:07 entrypoint.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 197121 233 Nov 16 20:09 keycloak-dockerfile
```

and the relevant part of the docker-compose keyloak section:

```
  keycloak:
    build: 
      dockerfile: ./keycloak-dockerfile
      context: ./
    ...
```